# Why this for loop does not work correctly?

Tags: matlab

I had this code below:

```
for i = 1:numel(Class1_mon_avg_synop) %size of Class1_mon_avg_synop is 1 x 12 cell
    ave(i) = Class1_mon_avg_synop{1,i}.sum_rrr24(1); % first row in sum_rrr24 is for January
    Jan_class1_avg{i,1} = ave(i);
end
for i = 1:numel(Class1_mon_avg_grid) %size of Class1_mon_avg_grid is 1 x 12 cell
    ave(i) = Class1_mon_avg_grid{1,i}.sum_precip(1);% first row in sum_precip is for January
    Jan_class1_avg{i,2} = ave(i);
end


% Do same for next month


for i = 1:numel(Class1_mon_avg_synop)
    ave(i) = mean(Class1_mon_avg_synop{1,i}.sum_rrr24(2)); % second row in sum_rrr24 is for February                    
    Feb_class1_avg{i,1} = ave(i);
end
for i = 1:numel(Class1_mon_avg_grid)
    ave(i) = mean(Class1_mon_avg_grid{1,i}.sum_precip(2)); % second row in sum_rrr24 is for February                      
    Feb_class1_avg{i,2} = ave(i);
end
% do same for all other month
% ...
```

As I should calculate this for all 12 months then I wrote this for loop:

```
for i = 1:numel(Class1_mon_avg_synop)
    ave(i) = Class1_mon_avg_synop{1,i}.sum_rrr24(i);
    ave(i) = Class1_mon_avg_grid{1,i}.sum_precip(i);
    ALLMONTHS_class1_avg{i,i} = ave(i);
    ALLMONTHS_class1_avg{i,i+1} = ave(i);  
end
```

But unfortunately, I got the wrong answer:

[image: Screen grab showing the contents of the cell array]

Because I think it must be 12  x 24 cell. 1st and 2nd column for January, 3rd, and 4th for February, etc...

Comment: So you want to use `2*i-1` and `2*i` instead of `i` and `i+1`? Do I understand the problem correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I think I spot two problems:
(a) you over-ride `ave(i)`, and (b) you put the value in `ALLMONTHS_class1_avg{i,i}` and `ALLMONTHS_class1_avg{i,i+1}`, so these are the diagonal and the row above the diagonal. 
According to your example you should end up having a 12-by-2 cell.

I suggest something like this:

```
for i = 1:numel(Class1_mon_avg_synop)
    ave_1(i) = Class1_mon_avg_synop{1,i}.sum_rrr24(i);
    ave_2(i) = Class1_mon_avg_grid{1,i}.sum_precip(i);
    ALLMONTHS_class1_avg{i,1} = ave_1(i);
    ALLMONTHS_class1_avg{i,2} = ave_2(i);  
end
```